# MyPy crashes due to syntax error in underlying modules

Tags: python, syntax, config, type-hinting, mypy

I'm trying to run MyPy on my package, but I'm running into issues due to a syntax error in an underlying package, that is not maintained by me.

I'm running `mypy` with the following `mypy.ini` file

```
[mypy]
files = **/*.py
ignore_missing_imports = True
pretty = True
show_error_codes = True
exclude = /(build|\..*)/$

[mypy-azure.storage.filedatalake.*]
ignore_errors = True
```

And the traceback that I'm getting is the following

```
LOG:  Parsing ~\.venv\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\filedatalake\_data_lake_file_client.py (azure.storage.filedatalake._data_lake_file_client)
LOG:  Bailing due to parse errors
LOG:  Build finished in 0.553 seconds with 4 modules, and 1 errors
~\.venv\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\filedatalake\_data_lake_file_client.py:280: error: Function has duplicate type signatures  [syntax]
        def set_file_expiry(
        ^
Found 1 error in 1 file (errors prevented further checking)
```

So basically I've made sure that any build directory or a directory starting with a dot (especially .venv) is not included as a direct source. Still it crashes, because it probably is used elsewhere in code that **does** include .venv packages and modules as sources. I'm not sure how to ignore these errors and let MyPy run normally. Whilst I can ignore some errors later on by including a module specific configuration, it won't let me ignore syntax errors.

What MyPy is having issues with is the `# type: <type>` that is included in the function definition of some of the functions in the module file.

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? ?

Comment: Sadly no, I didn't find a solution.